# The YouTube video on the Stack Teams website is set to private

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams, broken-link

On [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/resources/demo-using-collections-for-new-hire-onboarding), there's a link to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0kpkL7Dn-6E&). However, the video is private and cannot be viewed. The setting is incorrect